# group daily hours in a week using aggregate

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users.name) AS users'),
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT projects.name) AS projects'),
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT daily) AS daily'),
            DB::raw('SUM(hours) AS hours'),
            DB::raw('SUM(week) AS week'),
                   

        ];
        $range = $this->getRange();

        return DB::table('time_records')
                ->select($columns)
                ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'time_records.user_id')
                ->leftJoin('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'time_records.project_id')
                ->when($projectIds, function ($query) use ($projectIds) {
                    return $query->whereIn('week', $projectIds);
                })
                ->groupBy('week')
                ->get();
    }
```

> this is my output I don't know how to group the daily hours into a week. I need to get the total of hours as a week. Can Someone help me with this?

Comment: Why not just group by week and sum daily hours?

Comment: yeah, can u tell me how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [group daily hours in a week using aggregate functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73849060/group-daily-hours-in-a-week-using-aggregate-functions)